# How to disable model binding for one action method in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding, modelbinders, custom-model-binder

We are using custom model binders, how to disable model binding for one action method, so that i can directly post data from angular http post request,
I have taken different/new class as parameter for action method.
but due to custom model binders loosing posted data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can disable custom model binding for an action, but you can do it by (model) class type.

I'm guessing you've got something like this:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new CustomModelBinderClass();
```

The Binders Property is a dictionary mapping (model) types to model binder classes, so if you can use a unique model type in this one scenario, you should be able to change back to the default binder for that model type like this:

```
var defaultBinder = new DefaultModelBinder();
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(ModelThatNeedsDefaultBinding), defaultBinder);
```